# Sf2 Importing bundle services.yml from subdirectory

Tags: symfony, yaml

Is there a possibility to import a services.yml file from a subdir in config?

I've got a structure like this:

```
[Acme/MyBundle/Resources]

--[config]

----[routing]

----[services]

------[User]

--------services.yml

----[validation]

----routing.yml

----services.yml

----validation.yml
```

Now I want to import a file `Acme/MyBundle/Resources/config/services/User/services.yml`  into `Acme/MyBundle/Resources/config/services.yml`, which is loaded in `DependencyInjection/AcmeMyExtension`. The code in `Acme/MyBundle/Resources/config/services.yml` is:

```
imports:
    - { resource: "@AcmeMyBundle/Resources/config/services/User/services.yml" }

services:
    //other services
```

I'm getting error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'The file "@AcmeMyBundle/Resources/config/services/User/services.yml" does not exist (in: ., C:\wamp\www\dir\src\Acme\MyBundle\DependencyInjection/../Resources/config).' in C:\wamp\www\dir\app\cache\dev\classes.php:1518 
Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\dir\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\FileLoader.php(70): Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator->locate('@AcmeMyBundle/...', '.', false) #1 C:\wamp\www\dir\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader.php(97): Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\FileLoader->import('@AcmeMyBundle/...', NULL, false, 'services.yml') #2 C:\wamp\www\dir\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader.php(54): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader->parseImports(Array, 'services.yml') #3 C:\wamp\www\dir\src\Acme\MyBundle\DependencyInjection\AcmeMyExtension.php(26): Symfony\Co in C:\wamp\www\dir\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\FileLoader.php on line 100
```

The code of Acme/MyBundle/DependencyInjection/AcmeMyExtension.php:

```
<?php

namespace Core\MpgBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

/**
 * This is the class that loads and manages your bundle configuration
 *
 * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html}
 */
class CoreMpgExtension extends Extension
{

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use $loader->load('services/User/services.yml');

Comment: Yes, indeed, but it doesn't solve the problem completely - if I add another subfolders parallel to User, I need to edit the Extension file again and again - is there any option to tell loader to load all files in the config directory (no matter in what subfolder they are placed)? The other way is to import the User/services.yml into the services.yml file, but I don't know if it's possible?

Comment: In this case you can use the Finder Component : http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html . Iterate all files and load them

Comment: Thanks, it's very helpfull! But still I just can't believe Symfony2 doesn't provide this functionality by default... am I missing something? How can people collect hundreds of services in just one file, without any subfolders etc? There must be another, easier way to import one services.yml file into another..

Comment: Why do you need to collect hundreds of services in one file ? When you need to load a file containing service you just load it. If you want to avoid create xml or yml file to describe services you can use https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSDiExtraBundle . With this bundle you can directly describe service with annotations. see http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle/master/usage.

Comment: There is a way to import .yml files into another. ```imports:
    - { resource: onefile.yml }
    - { resource: twofile.yml }``` at the top of your services.yml file.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working by doing the following:

In `services.yml`

```
imports:
    - { resource: 'subdirectory\filename.yml' }
```

Now, as to why this is the case, instead of the typical `@Bundle\Path\To\File`? My suspicion is because the DependencyInjection class hasn't completed processing, the framework isn't able to use that annotation to figure out where things reside. Those more knowledgeable about internals can confirm.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to import other ressources in yml file, even if the files you would like to import are in subfolder.

For example, accept you have a file named `config.yml` and you would like to import others yml file under subfolder named `assets`, you could import your differents yml file like this:

```
#config.yml file
imports:
    - { resource: assets/design.yml }
    - { resource: assets/params.yml }
```

You can also import entire directories to load all the resources inside them:

```
#config.yml file
imports:
    - { resource: assets/ }
```

See for example symfony doc [here](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-import-config-files-with-glob-patterns)

Hope this could help you.